# Find entities that have two specific entries in a collection

Tags: java, hibernate

This has turned out to be really difficult to google for, so I'll try my luck here.

I have two classes like this:

```
@Entity
public class Cat {
    @Id
    private Integer catId;

    private String name;

    private String color;

    @OneToMany
    private List<Kitten> kittens;
}

@Entity
public class Kitten {
    @Id
    private Integer kittenId;

    private String name;

    private String color;

    @ManyToOne
    private Cat parent;
}
```

And I'm looking to find all grey `Cat` that has a `Kitten` with a name starting with P and that are white and a separate kitten that has a name starting with Q and is black. So far I've got this:

```
Criteria criteria = session.createCriteria(Cat.class);
criteria.add(Restriction.eq("color", "grey"));

criteria.createAlias("kittens", "k");

criteria.add(Restriction.and(
    Restriction.eq("k.color", "white"),
    Restriction.ilike("k.name", "P%")
    ));
criteria.add(Restriction.and(
    Restriction.eq("k.color", "black"),
    Restriction.ilike("k.name", "Q%")
    ));

List<Cat> results = criteria.setResultTransformer(Criteria.DISTINCT_ROOT_ENTITY).list();
```

Now this doesn't work and gives me no hits at all even though such a `Cat` exists. Removing the very last restriction set works just fine. I imagine I need a different approach than just adding another restriction for the second `Kitten` but I haven't managed to figure out what it is I want to do.

It's also important that I don't match a `Cat` with four kittens that have one of these properties each.

Answer (score 1):

The reason you fail to fetch after adding the second restrictions is that you tell criteria to find a kitten with all of those restriction: black and white - which of course doesnt exist unless it is shrodinger's cat.

You can accomplish this by joining cat with kittens twice: create two aliases for kittens: k1, k2 and restrict one by the first kitten and the second by the second kitten.

Comment: This sounds promising. I thought it might be a simple solution if one just knew how to approach it. I'll let you know how it goes once I get a chance to test it (a bit pressed for time right now).

Comment: Just tried this and I get a `QueryException` from Hibernate stating "duplicate association path on Kittens" when I try this. Googling it seems to have been a "bug" back in Hibernate 3, I'm stuck on 4.2 and I'm not sure if this has been changed in Hibernate 5, but upgrading is unfortunately not an option in my situation. =/

Comment: Bummer! Are you sure its a bug in Hibernate and not Criteria? It seems that Criteria is deprecated. Have you heard about queryDSL? It is much better for dynamic queries from my experience.  Ill try to verify that it works both in HQL and queryDSL and let you know.

Comment: Haven't heard of that. Is it available/compatible with Hibernate 4.2? I'll look into it and see if I can rework my solution to work with that instead. Cheers.

Answer (score 0):

*New answer based on comments:*

In SQL I think something like this would work. I don't know Hibernate, but you can use this as starting point to convert the concept into code.

```
Select 
C.name, count(distinct K.color)
From Cat C, Kitten K
Where
C.color = 'grey'
and C.id = K.catId
and (
  (K.color = 'white' and K.name like 'P%') 
  or 
  (K.color = 'black' and K.name like 'Q%')
)
group by C.name
having count(distinct K.color) = 2
```

This first joins the eligible Cats on the eligible Kittens. By itself that does not solve the problem (as evidenced by the Old Content below and the comment chain), but then if you add a grouping to count the number of distinct kitten colors that were found per cat, if it equals two then it means the cat has one of each kitten.

See this SQLFiddle which I used to test it out: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/ee93f5/1/0

---

*Old content (retained so that comments make sense):*

I don't know hibernate but I think the SQL should look like:

```
Select <your stuff>
From Cat C, Kitten K
Where
C.color = 'grey'
and C.id = K.catId (I guess Hibernate provides these keys automatically?)
and (
  (K.color = 'white' and K.name like 'P%') 
  or 
  (K.color = 'black' and K.name like 'Q%')
)
```

Basically, the two kitten constraints must be part of an OR clause which is added to overall constraint as an AND clause.

In your example, if I'm understanding the Hibernate code correctly, all of the constraints are added as AND clauses, so the result set will be empty because any Kitten row your Cat joins on cannot be black and white at the same time.

Comment: But even this SQL will only find me cats that have one of these two kittens. I'm specifically looking for cats that have *both* of them. Since this is a condensed example of a larger and more complex set of entities  I was hoping to keep my solution in Hibernate as it makes the search function a bit more manageable compare to generating SQL.

Comment: @SilverSnake Ah, okay, I see, yes this SQL won't work. Sure I understand, I was giving the SQL so that you can convert back into Hibernate code, since that was the most I could offer.

Comment: I appreciate the effort. The problem for me is that I'm a bit green with hibernate so I'm hoping someone can point me to the right Hibernate trick for this problem.

Comment: @SilverSnake In the absence of an elegant single-query solution, you could do a two pass approach. Find all grey cats that have a white P% kitten. Of those cats, find ones that have a black Q% kitten. I don't think it's ideal, but it's a thought if you find no other approach and need to move past this step. For Hibernate, that might manifest as a Restrictions.in() method in the second pass.